# Problemas com sizeof

Tags: c, c++, array

Estou tentando retornar o tamanho do *array*, mas está dando erro. O que fazer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *palavra[] = {"casa", "carro"};
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < sizeof(palavra);i++){ //Segmentation fault aqui.
        printf(palavra[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro não está nessa linha, está na debaixo, quando vai acessar o elemento. Acesso o elemento 0 e está ok, acesso o elemento 1 e está ok, quando vai acessar o 3 dá o erro. Porque está tentando acessar o 3? Por que o erro no cálculo errado do `sizeof`.

O `sizeof` pega o tamanho de todo o *array*, todo espaço ocupado na memória. No caso o *array* é do tipo ponteiro, e em arquitetura 32 bits possui o tamanho 4 bytes. Como são dois elementos, o *array* tem tamanho 8. O que você deseja é o tamanho 2. Então tem que dividir o tamanho do *array* pelo tamanho do elemento, assim dá o resultado esperado. 8 que é o tamanho total, dividido por 4 que é o tamanho do ponteiro, dá 2, que é o resultado correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *palavra[] = {"casa", "carro"};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(palavra) / sizeof(palavra[0]); i++) printf("%s", palavra[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/yhs0cm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/scgyauvb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ArrayLength.c).

Comment: Eu tentei usar este modo que você propôs mas o compilador ainda retorna segmentation fault.

Comment: @ThiagoMartendal você clicou nos *links* que eu coloquei na resposta? Lá mostra em dois compiladores diferentes que funciona. Você deve estar fazendo outra coisa. Coloque seu código no ideone e mostre o erro.

Comment: pronto consegui.

Comment: +1. Mas: "[...] quando vai acessar o 3 dá o erro.". Não seria "o 2"? (i.e. indexação de 0 a 1 para 2 itens no array)

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` retorna o tamanho da memoria alocada pelo ponteiro, não o numero dos elementos.

Pra percorrer com esse for voce precisa saber o numero de elementos do array e usar esse valor como condição de parada

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *palavra[] = {"casa", "carro"};
int tamanho = 2;
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        printf(palavra[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```